# Прошу помочь сделать ножку в ёлочке из звёздочек в javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: елочка]

Нужно сделать елочку с ножкой

```
  *
 ***
*****
  *
```

Вот мой код:

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let max = +prompt('Введите количество строк ');
let space = '';
let star = '';
while (i < max) {
  space = '';
  star = '';

  for (j = 0; j < max - i; j += 1) {
    space += ' ';
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j += 1) {
    star += '*';
  }

  console.log(space + star);
  i += 1;
}
```

Comment: А высота ножки всегда 1? Если да, то ножка просто повторяет верхушку. В чём проблема?))

Comment: Никак не могу понять как это сделать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто, берём кол-во строк которое ввёл ползователь, столько же раз добавляем пробелы, а в конце добавляем `*`.

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let max = +prompt('Введите количество строк ');
let space = '';
let star = '';
while (i < max) {
  space = '';
  star = '';

  for (j = 0; j < max - i; j += 1) {
    space += ' ';
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j += 1) {
    star += '*';
  }

  console.log(space + star);
  i += 1;
}
console.log(' '.repeat(max)+'*')
```

##### Без `repeat`:

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let max = +prompt('Введите количество строк ');
let space = '';
let star = '';
while (i < max) {
  space = '';
  star = '';

  for (j = 0; j < max - i; j += 1) {
    space += ' ';
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j += 1) {
    star += '*';
  }

  console.log(space + star);
  i += 1;
}
space = ''
for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) { space += ' ' }
console.log(space+'*')
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать без .repeat?

Comment: @ВячеславСиваш если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то прошу отметить его галочкой. (Слева от ответа)

Comment: Сппсибо!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Оставлю это тут как интересное решение с помощью [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) и [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd):

```js
const drawTree = (spaceCount, startCount) => console.log(
  ''
  .padStart(spaceCount, ' ')
  .padEnd(startCount, '*')
);

const linesCount = +prompt('Введите количество строк:');

for (let i = 1; i < linesCount; ++i) {
  drawTree(linesCount - i, linesCount - 1 + i);
}

drawTree(linesCount - 1, linesCount);
```